# How to Stop Multiple Android Studio Instance Pop up in Windows?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, intellij-idea, flutter, android-emulator

I recently updated my Android Studio to version 3.5.3 and was using the latest Flutter and Dart updates.
At random times the Android studio creates new instance of Android Studio for the same project I am working on.
[image]

I just realized, this is happening when I do a change in the gradle file and save it. Also if I close any of the window, the whole android studio closes.
Is it something to do with any settings?

Comment: `"At random times ..."` - you mean without any action from you?

Comment: It happens when I do a change in the gradle file and save

Comment: Have you checked idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?